# How can I get the titles for Lordhadears' quest?

Tags: half-minute-hero

The [Hero 30 wiki](http://halfminutehero.wikia.com/wiki/Hero_30) doesn't cover this quest just yet, so:

- How can I get the Red Diamond title?
- How can I get the Ear Killer title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Red Diamond** title is obtained by obtaining Yohei (the first town's knight) as a companion by retrieving the red diamond in the southmost cave. This is the obvious course of action, given that obtaining $1,000 for Yohei and $200 for the boat and $many to the goddess to get enough time to complete the quest [is no easy feat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbTcO.jpg), while leveling up enough to take the middle boss on your own probably takes more time than it saves.

The **Ear Killer** title, as well as the Complete status for this map, is obtained by taking a little detour to the island just south of the ship dock.